# PegKit custom include files for custom actions

Tags: objective-c, pegkit

I have actions with custom objects. I'd like to not have to copy and paste all the #imports each time I generate the parser. Is this possible with some `@begin` or some other directive.

for example:

```
mycustomRule: word {
    PUSH([[MyCoolNewObject alloc] initWith:POP_STR()]);
};
```

It all generates perfectly but then when trying to compile obviously the generated file is missing the `#import "MyCoolNewObject.h"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator of [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) here.

PEGKit (but not ParseKit) has a feature inspired by ANTLR called **"Grammar Actions"**. Grammar Actions are a way to do exactly what you are looking for: inserting arbitrary code in various places in your Parser's .h and .m files. They must be placed at the top of your grammar before any rules are listed.

Use [PEGKit tag v0.3.6](https://github.com/itod/pegkit/releases/tag/v0.3.6) or later (or HEAD of master).

Here are all of the Grammar Actions currently available, along with a description of where their bodies are inserted in the source code of your generated parser:

**In the .h file:**

- **`@h`** - top of .h file
- **`@interface`** - inside the `@interface` portion of header

**In the .m file:**

- **`@m`** - top of .m file
- **`@extension`** - inside a private `@interface MyParser ()` class extension in the .m file
- **`@ivars`** - private ivars inside the `@implementation MyParser {}` in the .m file
- **`@implementation`** - inside your parser's `@implementation`. A place for defining methods.
- **`@init`** - inside your parser's `init` method
- **`@dealloc`** - inside your parser's `dealloc` method if ARC is not enabled
- **`@before`** - setup code goes here. executed before parsing begins.
- **`@after`** - tear down code goes here. executed after parsing ends.

(notice that the `@before` and `@after` Grammar Actions listed here are distinct from the `@before` and `@after` which may also be placed in each individual rule.)

For your current needs, the `@m` Grammar Action is the correct choice. So add this to the top of your grammar:

```
@m {
#import "MyCoolNewObject.h"
}
```